# Trigger to handle multiple inserts

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a button in my form that is submitting input into many different tables. I created  WHEN-BUTTON_PRESSED trigger:

```
BEGIN
            INSERT INTO table_a 
        VALUES (
    :new.emp_ID,
    :new.surname,
    :new.name,
    :new.hired_date,
    :new.salary);
      commit;
       INSERT INTO table_b
       VALUES (
     :new.emp_ID,
     :new.svr,
     :new.svr_id,
     :new.trg);  
    commit;
end;
```

I cannot use **INSERT ALL** because it is Oracle 6i. After execution above statement form freezes and stops responding . I believe it is due to referential integrity of data as those tables have the same primary keys. Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: if your database is 10g or higher you can create a database function and then use INSERT ALL into that function and call the function in your when-button-pressed

Comment: @psaraj12 yes however it is not and I can't upgrade. Any workarounds ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screen is getting freeze because of multiple commits use the below after the last insert or end of the when button pressed code whatever you want to commit

```
POST;
commit;
```